# Assigning a type uintptr to uint64 in Golang

Tags: pointers, go, variable-assignment

I'm trying to assign the value found in a variable of type `uintptr` to a `uint64` variable in Go. Using

```
myVar = valFromSystem
```

gives me

> cannot use `valFromSystem` (type `uintptr`) as type `uint64` in assignment

And trying

```
myVar = *valFromSystem
```

gives me

> invalid indirect of valFromSystem (type uintptr)

Is there a way to pull the value pointed to by valFromSystem to assign to `myVar`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, cast `valFromSystem` into an `unsafe.Pointer`. An `unsafe.Pointer` can be casted into any pointer type. Next, cast the `unsafe.Pointer` into a pointer to whatever type of data `valFromSystem` points to, e.g. an `uint64`.

```
ptrFromSystem = (*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(valFromSystem))
```

If you just want to get the value of the pointer (without dereferencing it), you can use a direct cast:

```
uint64FromSystem = uint64(valFromSystem)
```

Though remember that you should use the type `uintptr` when using pointers as integers.

Comment: look here on how to use unsafe pointers "safely".  In particular, never store the pointer anywhere, you must derreference it immediately (unless you're just going to print the value of the pointer or something)...    https://golangdoc.github.io/pkg/1.8/unsafe/index.html#ArbitraryType